# In SQL Server, is it possible to have a PRIMARY KEY on a table without either CLUSTERED or NONCLUSTERED indexes on the same key?

Tags: sql-server-2008, index, clustered-index, clustered-primary-key

In Sql Server (2008), is it possible to have a `PRIMARY KEY` on a set of columns without either `CLUSTERED` or `NONCLUSTERED` indexes on the same set of columns?

I am aware of the fact that `PRIMARY KEY` and `CLUSTERED INDEX` key are separate concepts and that we can create `PRIMARY KEY` without `CLUSTERED INDEX` on it (see below).

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Sample 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Sample_SeqGUID_Col1 PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (SeqGUID_Col1)
```

But my question is to see if it is possible to create `PRIMARY KEY` on a table without a `CLUSTERED` or `NONCLUSTERED` index on it.

Comment: Thank Mark for the editing. I will keep those points in mind for my next post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In short, no. A primary key by definition requires uniqueness, an index on the primary key field is the database engines route to enforcing this constraint.

From [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191236.aspx):

> When you specify a PRIMARY KEY constraint for a table, the Database
>   Engine enforces data uniqueness by creating a unique index for the
>   primary key columns. This index also permits fast access to data when
>   the primary key is used in queries. Therefore, the primary keys that
>   are chosen must follow the rules for creating unique indexes.

Answer (score 8):

No, a primary key constraint is always enforced in SQL-Server by a unique index. The index may be clustered or unclustered. If you don't specify which type, default is `CLUSTERED` for the primary key. From [MSDN documentation, `CREATE TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> `CLUSTERED | NONCLUSTERED`
>
> Indicate that a clustered or a nonclustered index is created for the `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint. `PRIMARY KEY` constraints default to `CLUSTERED` and `UNIQUE` constraints default to `NONCLUSTERED`.
>
> In a `CREATE TABLE` statement, `CLUSTERED` can be specified for only one constraint. If `CLUSTERED` is specified for a `UNIQUE` constraint and a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint is also specified, the `PRIMARY KEY` defaults to `NONCLUSTERED`.